# generating a hemispherical surface with triangular_mesh and representing a data( as value or as colors) at each vertex

Tags: python, mayavi

I want to generate a surface which should look like a hemisphere.. What I have done so far is to read an already existing BEM mesh and try to show the scalar values on it. But now I have to show the scalar values on a hemisphere instead of the Bem mesh. And I don't know how to generate using a triangular mesh that looks like an hemisphere.

This hemisphere needs to contain a set of N number of points(x,y,z)[using the mlab.triangular_mesh] and at each vertex I need to represent N data(float) either as a value or using variations in colormap(eg: blue(lowest value of the data) to red(highest value of the data)). data=its an array of size 2562, a set of float values, could be randomly generated as its part of another codes. Points were part of another set of code too.its of shape(2562,3). but the shape is not a hemisphere
This was the program I used for viewing using the BEM surface

```
fname = data_path + '/subjects/sample/bem/sample-5120-5120-5120-bem-sol.fif'
surfaces = mne.read_bem_surfaces(fname, add_geom=True)
print "Number of surfaces : %d" % len(surfaces) 
head_col = (0.95, 0.83, 0.83)  # light pink
colors = [head_col]
try:
     from enthought.mayavi import mlab
except:
     from mayavi import mlab
mlab.figure(size=(600, 600), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))
for c, surf in zip(colors, surfaces):
    points = surf['rr']
    faces = surf['tris']
    s=data
    mlab.triangular_mesh(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2],faces,color=c, opacity=1,scalars=s[:,0])



#mesh= mlab.triangular_mesh(x,y,z,triangles,representation='wireframe',opacity=0)        #point_data=mesh.mlab_source.dataset.point_data
#point_data.scalars=t
#point_data.scalars.name='Point data'
#mesh2=  mlab.pipeline.set_active_attribute(mesh,point_scalars='Point data')
```

Comment: Great. What's your question?

Comment: what did you try so far? Where do you get errors or where is the result your code gives you not agreeing with what you expected it to give?

Comment: I would like to know how I should do it. Bcos when I tried I ended up with surface colored from top to bottom with the colormap instead of taking the values and the triangles were colored instead of just the vertices.. :( I'm pretty new to python and mayavi. Any suggestions or help would be good.. Thanx in advance!

Comment: @didi good, that is a start. Please show us what code you have so far, and we can look and see where the problem may be

Comment: I tried seeing how a few examples have been done on this forum and tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out your question is not very clear, and does not include an easily reproducible example -- your example would take considerable work for us to reproduce and you have not described the steps you have taken very clearly.

What you are *trying* to do is easy. Scalars can be defined for each vertex (i.e., each VTK point):

```
surf = mlab.triangular_mesh(x,y,z,triangles)
surf.mlab_source.scalars = t
```

And you need to set a flag to get them to appear, which I think might be your problem:

```
surf.actor.mapper.scalar_visibility=True
```

Here is some code to generate a half-sphere. It produces a VTK polydata. I'm not 100% sure if the mayavi source is the same source type as `triangular_mesh` but I think it is.

```
res = 250. #desired resolution (number of samples on sphere)
phi,theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:np.pi/res, 0:np.pi:np.pi/res]

x=np.cos(theta) * np.sin(phi)
y=np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
z=np.cos(phi)

mlab.mesh(x,y,z,color=(1,1,1))
```

Comment: Thnak you. Well,What I have done so far is to read an already existing BEM mesh and try to show the scalar values on it. But now I have to show the scalar values on a hemisphere instead of the Bem mesh. And I don't know how to generate a mesh that looks like an hemisphere

Comment: Okay. You should make your question more clear because I definitely did not decipher that you were asking for that.  Some code to do that is included in the answer now.